# A version of `\ignorespaces` that doesn't overspill the line

Tags: tables, spacing, line-breaking, linguistics

I’m using commands based on the tabular environment to align pairs of words in a linguistics book. After some pairs, I use `\ignorespaces` to suppress spacing, but this causes lines to overspill. Is there an alternative that avoids this?

The MWE provided shows two commands: `\gloss` which puts one argument above the next and then inserts a space before the next stacked pair, and `\glom` which inserts a hyphen after each argument and gobbles up the following spaces. (These are toy versions of the macros I’m actually using, but they highlight the issue.)

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=25mm]{geometry}

\newcommand\glom[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\itshape#1-\\#2-\end{tabular}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\gloss[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\itshape#1\\#2\end{tabular} }

\begin{document}

\noindent 
Compare the normal linebreak of this line with how%
\rlap{\raisebox{-40ex}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{.5pt}{43ex}}} 
\verb"\glom" overspills:
\medskip

\noindent
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\medskip

\noindent
What I'd like is an automatic line break: 
\medskip

\noindent
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}%
\linebreak
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\medskip

\noindent
By itself, \verb"\gloss" respects linebreaks: \gloss{essai}{attempt}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are several linguistics packages that provide this functionality, for example [`gb4e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/gb4e/gb4e-doc.pdf). Maybe that would be an option for your use case?

Comment: I've used most of these packages in the past. They all have shortcomings, so I started using my own macros (now reduced to a single macro, thanks to `ifthen` / `ifmtarg`). This allows me to build in a lot of project-specific features. For the record, I've found John Frampton’s `expex` the best (lets you do the most fiddling).

Comment: Maybe `\allowbreak\ignorespaces`??

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes An improvement but not a fix. Using `\newcommand\glom[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\itshape#1-\\#2-\end{tabular}\allowbreak\ignorespaces}`, the `\gloss` pair following `\glom` now goes onto the next line, but the `\glom` pair still overspills.

Comment: Because of the width of these units, you need to place the *paragraph* inside a `sloppypar` environment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That does exactly what I want. If you write an answer, I'll tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP asked me to put my comments into an answer.  Initially, I had suggested to add `\allowbreak` in the definition of `\glom`, immediately prior to the `\ignorespaces`.  This had the effect of allowing a break between `\glom` and `\gloss`, but it did not prevent `\glom` from overrunning the margin.  Also, it is not wholly clear if the OP really would like to permit a line break between `\glom` and `\gloss`.

It then became clear the issue is that the use of `tabular` in a double-wide configuration really limited the number of available breakpoints.  The solution I then profferred by way of comment was to enclose the collection in a `sloppypar`.  That seemed to provide the proper resolution.  The earlier suggestion of `\allowbreak` could be incorporated or not, at the OP's discretion.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=25mm]{geometry}

\newcommand\glom[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\itshape#1-\\#2-\end{tabular}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\gloss[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\itshape#1\\#2\end{tabular} }

\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\noindent
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have problems, with so wide items and so few line break points, so you should probably use `flushleft`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=25mm]{geometry}

\newcommand\glom[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\itshape#1-\\#2-\end{tabular}%
  \ignorespaces
}
\newcommand\gloss[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\itshape#1\\#2\end{tabular}%
  \space\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \makebox[\textwidth][r]{\kern-0.4pt\smash{\vrule width 0.4pt depth 30ex height 2ex}}%
}%
Compare the normal linebreak of this line with how
\verb"\glom" overspills:
\begin{flushleft}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\glom{contre}{counter}
\gloss{essai}{attempt}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]